# Submitting changes to excel file using Excel Interop in C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am still stuck in this code and bugs keep showing up..
I have excel file that is almost 24 columns, I am trying to adapt it to a 7 column excel file because the software I have works only on 7 columns and I don't want to re write the software from the beginning, so you will see some deletion and isertion of columns..

I have 5 columns inside this excel file that have either "x" value or null.

what I am trying to do is to create a new column between range A1,and B1 that is called category, so if there is an x in column 5, i write E in the category field, else if the x is in the 6th column then I write P in the category column.. and so on.
And then I need to delete these 5 columns that I no longer need (Range E1:I1)

The problem is when I debug the code, I can see that the values[,] have the column inserted, and the values has been transfered correctly, but when the temp_data.csv is produced, it has the new excel file after deletion so now it contains 11 columns, but the new Category column together with the values are not there...

```
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(p_sUBKPath, Type.Missing, false, 4, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = ws.UsedRange;

                // delete columns that we don't need from the new excel file
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range2 = ws.get_Range("A1","A1"); 
                range2.EntireColumn.Delete();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range3 = ws.get_Range("B1", "B1");
                range3.EntireColumn.Delete();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range4 = ws.get_Range("D1", "L1");
                range4.EntireColumn.Delete();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range5 = ws.get_Range("I1", "M1");
                range5.EntireColumn.Delete();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range6 = ws.get_Range("K1", "K1");
                range6.EntireColumn.Delete();

                //insert a new column ( Category)
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range7 = ws.get_Range("B1", "B1");
                range7.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight);


                object[,] tempVal = (object[,])range.Value2;
                tempVal[1, 2] = (object)"Category";

                for (int row = 2; row <= tempVal.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
                {

                    try
                    {

                        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)tempVal[row, 5])) && (string)tempVal[row, 5] == "x")
                        {
                            tempVal[row, 2] = (string)"E";
                        }
                        else if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)tempVal[row, 6])) && (string)tempVal[row, 6] == "x")
                        {
                            tempVal[row, 2] = (string)"P";


                        }
                        else if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)tempVal[row, 7])) && (string)tempVal[row, 7] == "x")
                        {
                            tempVal[row, 2] = (string)"Phy";


                        }
                        else if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)tempVal[row, 8])) && (string)tempVal[row, 8] == "x")
                        {
                            tempVal[row, 2] = (string)"L";


                        }
                        else if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempVal[row, 9].ToString())) && (string)tempVal[row, 9] == "x")
                        {
                            tempVal[row, 2] = (string)"Ex";


                        }
                        else
                            MessageBox.Show("unknow");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }


                }


                object[,] values = tempVal;
if (Convert.ToString(values[1, 1]).ToUpper().Trim() == "SHORT NAME" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 2]).ToUpper().Trim() == "CATEGORY" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 3]).ToUpper().Trim() == "LONG NAME EN" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 4]).ToUpper().Trim() == "LONG NAME DE" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 5]).ToUpper().Trim() == "ELEMENT" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 6]).ToUpper().Trim() == "PROPERNAME" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 7]).ToUpper().Trim() == "PHYSICAL" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 8]).ToUpper().Trim() == "LOGICAL" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 9]).ToUpper().Trim() == "EXTENSION" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 10]).ToUpper().Trim() == "CREATED BY" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 11]).ToUpper().Trim() == "CREATED ON" && Convert.ToString(values[1, 12]).ToUpper().Trim() == "STATE")

                {
                    for (int row = 1; row <= values.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
                        for (int col = 1; col <= values.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
                        {
                            string value = Convert.ToString(values[row, col]);

                            if (value.Contains(","))
                            {
                                range.Cells.set_Item(row, col, value.Replace(",", p_sPsuedostring));
                            }
                            if (value.Contains("    "))
                            {
                                range.Cells.set_Item(row, col, value.Replace("  ", p_sPsuedostring + "    " + p_sPsuedostring));
                            }
                        }
                    if (File.Exists(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\Data_Temp.csv")) 
                        File.Delete(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\Data_Temp.csv");

                   //Save the Latest databse as Data_Temp.csv
                    ws.SaveAs(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\Data_Temp.csv", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    xl.DisplayAlerts = true;
                    try
                    {
                        xl.Workbooks[1].Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                    xl.Application.Quit();
                    xl.Quit();
                    l_bClosedSuccessfully = true;
```

Comment: I have few questions `1` Why are you deleting the columns before inserting the column "Category" `2` Can multiple columns have "x" or is it just 1 column? `3` If your 7th Column has "X" then why are you writing "Phy" in the category column? Shouldn't it be "G"?

Comment: Remember when you delete Col A, the current Col B become Col A. So can you give me the names of the columns you want to delete before actually deleting them.

Comment: Dear Siddharth, I am actually deleting the columns that I don't need ( which do not include the columns that contain the x value) they are just extra columns. '2' it is only one x for each row in one of the 5 columns, so the x could occur only in one column between these 5 for a single row. '3' the p and phy and E are values related to my project for example E means element, PHY means physical..etc

Comment: ok Can you give me the name of those columns? i.e before they are deleted...

Comment: Domain Name was the first column in the file, but I deleted it and I followed the file manually to see the changes in ranges that happened. I mean I was aware that when I delete E the code will shift backwards and I have to start counting from the beginning

Comment: they are alphabatically ordered as they are in excel, but I am using the first cell of each column as a column name to represent what the column is about.but maybe you got confused about the P and PHY and L, these are values that have nothing to do with the 
columns order, these are shortcuts for words I need in the software. they are Element,Propername,Physical,Logical,Extension each of these columns have a value of either x or null if it is x in physical, i would write PHY in the second column

Comment: You still didn't get me... Let me try again... open the Excel File manually and then tell me which columns need to be deleted. Check visually and then tell me the column names.

Comment: A,c,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,t,u,v,w,x,AA

Comment: Thank you :) One moment.. Posting the code

Answer (score 1):

Based on your above comments, let's say your Excel File looks like this. I have colored the columns Yellow which needs to be deleted.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**Logic**:

1. Delete the columns in reverse order so that the sequence of the columns do not change else you will have to account for the newly shifted columns
2. Avoid using `usedrange`. `UsedRange` can also include unnecessary rows/columns making your code slower. I am finding the last cell which has data and then using it's `.Row` and `.Column` property to construct my range which contains "X"
3. Use `.Find` and .`Findnext` to search for "X" in your range. Once you find that, get th found cell's column number and subtract 2 from it. Since you will have only 5 columns, simply use an `IF` condition to check what is the value of the Column after you subtract 2 from it and then decide on the `keyword` that you want to use.

**Code**:

Try this code (TRIED AND TESTED)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Excel.Range Rng, aCell, bCell;
            String sMsg = "";

            object misValue = Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.Visible = true;

            //~~> Open a File (Chnage filename as applicable)
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\MyFile.xlsx",
                         0, true, 5, "", "", true,

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
            "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            //~~> Set Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to work with
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //~~> Delete relevant columns in reverse order
            //A,c,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,t,u,v,w,x,AA

            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("AA1", "AA1").EntireColumn.Delete();
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("T1", "X1").EntireColumn.Delete();
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("F1", "N1").EntireColumn.Delete();
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C1", "C1").EntireColumn.Delete();
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireColumn.Delete();

            //~~> Insert the Category Column
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1").EntireColumn.Insert(
            Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight);

            //~~> get the last row and the last column of your data range
            //~~> This is much better than using usedrange  which might
            //'~~> include unnecessary ranges
            int lRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(
                       Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing).Row;
            int lCol = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(
                       Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing).Column;

            String Addr = xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, lCol].Address;
            //~~> This is to get the column name from column number
            String ColName = Addr.Split('$')[1];

            //~~> This is your data range. I am assuming that Row 1 has headers
            Rng = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C2:" + ColName + lRow, misValue);

            //~~> Find the first occurance of "X"
            aCell = Rng.Find("X",misValue,Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                    Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,misValue,
                    Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,misValue,misValue,misValue);

            //~~> Find the next occurance of "X" using FindNext
            if(aCell != null)
            {
                //~~> Get the column number and subtract 2 from it
                int col = aCell.Column-2;

                //~~> Choose the relevant keyword
                if (col == 1)
                {
                    sMsg = "Element";
                }
                else if (col == 2)
                {
                    sMsg = "propername";
                }
                else if (col == 3)
                {
                    sMsg = "physical";
                }
                else if (col == 4)
                {
                    sMsg = "logical";
                }
                else if (col == 5)
                {
                    sMsg = "extension";
                }

                //~~> Populate the Category Column
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[aCell.Row, 2].Value = sMsg;

                string sFirstFoundAddress = aCell.get_Address(true, true,
                Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, misValue, misValue);

                bCell = Rng.Cells.FindNext(aCell);

                string sAddress = bCell.get_Address(true, true,
                Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, misValue, misValue);

                //~~> FindNext until the first found cell is found again
                While (!sAddress.Equals(sFirstFoundAddress))
                {
                    //~~> Get the column number and subtract 2 from it
                    col = bCell.Column-2;

                    //~~> Choose the relevant keyword
                    if (col == 1)
                    {
                        sMsg = "Element";
                    }
                    else if (col == 2)
                    {
                        sMsg = "propername";
                    }
                    else if (col == 3)
                    {
                        sMsg = "physical";
                    }
                    else if (col == 4)
                    {
                        sMsg = "logical";
                    }
                    else if (col == 5)
                    {
                        sMsg = "extension";
                    }

                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[bCell.Row, 2].Value = sMsg;

                    bCell = Rng.Cells.FindNext(bCell);

                    sAddress = bCell.get_Address(true, true,
                    Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, misValue, misValue);
                }
            }

            //~~> Once done close and quit Excel
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.Quit();

            //~~> CleanUp
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlexcel);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenShot** (After the code is run):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it, but I think I need time to implement it your way, because the code I am working on is not mine and it is very big and the variable names are used everywhere so I want to make sure that when I implement it nothing elsewhere will be affected, thanks again I will work on it now :)

Comment: Can you point me to the place where I can use my own keywords in the second category? not the first row's value, because instead of Element, I want to write E, because that's how it works in the other parts of the code, so it only accepts such a value.

Comment: And where are you picking `element` from?

Comment: Because actually the x goes only in rows from O to S in your example, so it is only between these 5 columns

Comment: Element,propername,physical,logical,extension
this is the order

Comment: And how are you deciding which one to use?

Comment: for each row, only one of these columns will have x, and the rest are null. so after extracting the info to Category, I am deleting all these 5 columns

Comment: I understand that part but my question is how are you deciding what to use from `Element,propername,physical,logical,extension`?

Comment: because they will look like (null,null,x,null,null) so that means it is physical. in the next row they will look like (x,null,null,null,null) so it is an element.

Comment: I will work to adapt it to my code. Anyway,i think you got your MVP for a reason :P thank you again

Comment: I will recommend you for one :P